# Handling sounds that match strings?

Tags: c#, audio

I'm making a random name generator. Problem is, I have many names, and I probably added them in a stupid way. I added the names to two lists like this...

```
        listFO.Add("Sir");
        listFO.Add("Lady");
        listFO.Add("Captain");
        listFO.Add("Mr");
        listFO.Add("Ms");
```

and the other like this

```
        listFN.Add("Gambler");
        listFN.Add("Katja");
        listFN.Add("John");
        listFN.Add("Nillo");
```

just with many more names.
Now other than the fact that I probably added these names in an inefficient way - what would be an efficient way of making a program that sees a name like 'CaptainNillo' and plays a sound called 'Captain.wav' first and then Nillo.wav' next?

Comment: Is your parameter going to be a full name (e.g. `CaptainNillo`) or do you have both first and last names available separately? This makes the solution either trivial or considerably more difficult with a number of caveats.

Comment: There should be 1 soundfile for each seperate name, otherwise I would have to record more than 10000 sound files! :D

Comment: Are you asking about parsing text with respect to those two list or how to play a sound or how to do it in background or how to "see" text to parse or everything of it?

Comment: I'm guessing a little bit of everything.
How to do it in the background? You mean threadding? I have that covered, and playing a sound, got it covered too.
"seeing" text to parse, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are sure about this format:

```
string input = "CaptainNillo";
string first = listFO.FirstOrDefault(x => input.StartsWith(x));
string second = listFN.FirstOrDefault(x => input.EndsWith(x));
if (first != null && second != null)
   // play first.wav and second.was
```